# How do the initial conditions change when I achieve transformation on the heat equation

Tags: linear-transformations, heat-equation, change-of-variable

Let us consider 1D heat equation:
$u_t = u_{xx}, x∈[0,2]$
subjected to zero Neumann Boundary conditions: $u_x (0,t) = u_x (2,t) = 0$.
The initial conditions: $u(x,0) = x$.

Now, let us introduce a new variable $\xi$, where $\xi =  (1/2) x$ and $\xi∈[0,1]$. Considering the new variable and the chain rule of derivative the previous heat equation becomes:
$$u_t = (1/4) u_{\xi\xi}$$
How will the initial conditions become after we achieved the transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you call $\hat u(\xi,t)$ your new function,  $\hat u(\xi,t)=u(x,t)$, you have $\hat u(\xi,0)=u(x,0)=x=2\xi$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you recommend a reference where I can find a practical examples of such transformations?

Comment: These linear transformations (in space or time) are used sometimes to eliminate coefficients in the equation. So if you have something like $u_t=4u_{xx}$, you can transform into the canonical form $\hat u_t=\hat u_{xx}$ by either transforming time or space by a factor, as in your example. In other cases, you transform your variables to reduce the problem to one on $[0,1]$ for which you already found the closed form of the solution, etc. Nonlinear transformations are also used, but those are more subtle. For example, the Cole-Hopf transformation to reduce Burgers' equation to the heat equation.

Comment: But I dont think these things are collected in any book. They are used when convenient.

Comment: Thank you so much for your information, it was useful. I checked the Cole-Hopf transformation you mention. In that transformation we change the unknown variable, but references I am searching for are those ones which discuss changing the independent variable, for example the space x.

Comment: That is right. There is also the Kelvin transform, which changes both the independent and dependent variables.

Comment: By the way do you know about Algebraic Grid Generation?

Comment: No, I do not. .